# Why would multiple SessionStateStoreProviders be instantiated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-express

I'm working on a Redis `SessionStateStoreProvider` that [can be found here](https://github.com/TheCloudlessSky/Harbour.RedisSessionStateStore). In my `web.config`, I add the following in the `system.web` element.

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisSessionStateProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="RedisSessionStateProvider" 
         type="Harbour.RedisSessionStateStore.RedisSessionStateStoreProvider" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

However, when I start the application (an MVC3 application using the built in VS Web Server), **two** instances of the `RedisSessionStateProvider` are created. This can be verified by setting a break point on the constructor. I've tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding but it didn't fix it. When the application is closed down, both providers *are* disposed.

Something interesting to note is that the breakpoint icons are as follows:

[image: breakpoints]

I can't seem to [find any documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx) on the second icon.

Interestingly enough, when I switch to IIS Express, two instances are created. However, when I refresh the page after it's loaded, a ***third*** instances is created. What's even more weird is that after a few seconds it gets disposed!

I can't find any documentation supporting this behaviour. Does anyone have any info on this? Is this by design? Could this be because of multiple worker processes?

Comment: Have you ever figured out what caused the issue?

Comment: @Shedal - Nope :(. I don't have time right now, but what we could do is use Reflector/some other decompiler and analyze the graph of calls made to instantiate the provider.

Comment: I just had a thought. ASP.NET may spawn multiple HttpApplication instances per AppDomain. This is in order to be able to process multiple HTTP requests in parallel. In that case, I assume each HttpApplication instance also instantiates its own session state provider. Wouldn't that explain the issue?

Comment: @Shedal - It very well could be. However, my `Application_Start` is only called once.

Comment: This and many other strange things can happen when web sites are set up as Web Gardens (Maximum Worker Processes > 1) in the Application Pool.

Comment: (just noticed that it's a two year old question :-)) the other icon indicate that a thread other than the one you attached to have hit this break, your Application_Start won't run twice that's for sure because it's run once when the app domain is first loaded into the hosting application pool.

Comment: what happens if you try it on iis instead of iis express?